# EF Core not delete related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I try to remove my entity with it related entity, but Entity Framework doen't want to do this.

Here is the code:

```
        var tr = _context.Trees
            .Include(x => x.Translation)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2);

        _context.Remove(tr);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

Context:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Tree>().ToTable("h_tree");
  modelBuilder.Entity<Tree>().HasOne(x => x.Translation);
```

Tree class:

```
public class Tree 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Translation Translation { get; set; }
}
```

Anyone have idea why related entity can't be removed?

Translation class:

```
public class Translation 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Pl { get; set; }
    public string En { get; set; }
    public string De { get; set; }
    public string Cz { get; set; }
    public string It { get; set; }
    public string Ru { get; set; }
    public string Fr { get; set; }

    public Translation()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there actualy a record with id == 2 in the dataset?

Comment: Yes of course. This is a EF log: 
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DELETE FROM [cat].[h_tree]
      WHERE [id] = @p0;
      SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed to say whether this is a one-to-one or one-to-many relationship.

`.HasOne()` needs to be paired with a `.With*()` method. Either `.WithOne()` or `.WithMany()`.

---

It seems your Translation class is missing a Foreign key.

Add a property called `TreeId` and use that in your `.WithOne()` call.

Comment: I tried this syntax:                 modelBuilder.Entity<Tree>().HasOne(x => x.Translation).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have following error: The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship that was detected between 'Tree.Translation' and 'Translation'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property.

Comment: @bielu000 So what *is* your foreign key field in `Translation`and why didn't you put it in your .WithOne method?

Comment: What I need put into WithOne method? 
This syntaxt is not correct:                 modelBuilder.Entity<Tree>().HasOne(x => x.Translation).WithOne(x => x.Id) I have an error: "                modelBuilder.Entity<Tree>().HasOne(x => x.Translation).WithOne(x => x.Id)"

Comment: @bielu000 I have no idea because I don't know what your `Translation` class looks like. What *is* your foreign key there?

Comment: I added my translation class above.

Comment: Getting entity from database including related entity works propely, updating too, but not removing.

Comment: @bielu000 "related" is a broad term. I strongly recommend you reading the [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) section of the documentation. The way you configured the relationship, `Translation` is the **principal** and `Tree` is the **dependent** having `TranslationId` FK. There is no way deleting the dependent to delete the principal.